# My right axis is cut off...how do I correct it?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, charts, d3.js

I am creating an `svg` chart with both a right and left axis. I've created a chart with both a right and a left axis. However, the right axis is getting cut off. See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eWx4D/)

What I've tried:

1. I've tried adjusting the width of the .background and .plot to wider and narrower
2. I've tried setting the z-index of the axis labels to 9999
3. I've tried to zoom into the svg by setting the width and height of .background to 90%
4. I've tried moving the text label to the left, but then it starts bleeding into the plot area
5. I've tried setting overflow of the .background to visible

I'm out of ideas. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eWx4D/5/

I adjusted the width of:

```
<g class="graph line-graph vertical">
<rect y="0" x="0" width="1000" height="301" class="background"/>
```

I changed the width from `900` and added `1` pixel of height to cover the bleeding bg ..

Comment: thx, but I don't believe this is the optimal solution. Changing background color shows the flaws as the label axis bleeds: http://jsfiddle.net/eWx4D/3/

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing the width to `900`, you can set the width to `1000` and you solve your problem.

```
<svg ... width="900" viewBox="0 0 900 300">
```

But if you want to keep the `width="900"` you can also set the `viewBox` width to 1000 and your chart will be scaled to the size of the svg.

```
<svg ... width="900" viewBox="0 0 1000 300">
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't believe either of these are "optimal". Changing svg's background-color to red shows the flaws (the axis labels bleed): http://jsfiddle.net/eWx4D/3/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using margins:

```
var plotWidth = 1000;
var plotHeight = 600;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = plotWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = plotHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
// etc.

svg = d3.select("#mydiv").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

For me it's easier to think about, and adjust as needed.